# How to recover the files from git hub that disappeared after team member's commit and push?

Tags: github, push, commit, recover

It is almost done of a project. We are all 4 team members. We are working to make a shopping mall website. We are using Eclipse version 2023.06, based on M V C model 2 and J S P.  30mins ago I merged team member's commit&push then my and other member's files were disappeared, it likes almost reset.

A team who committed and pushed, said he got some problems at git hub before this situation. The problem is, his branch is feature/s th but he forgot to checkout so he tried to add, commit in main.
The first thing was only push the files so he forced push. Then I merged then it happened.

All of ways that I searched. git checkout  -- , and checked all of my repository's history. All of git log.